# best way to prevent each on a nil variable on rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a query that is checking if a certain values exist in the DB and returns an array if they exist

```
@canEditTask = Accessor.where("accessor_id = ? AND access_right = ?", current_user, true)
```

The problem is that this can return nil
        @taskEdit = @canEditTask

but my each method in my html still fails due to nil `undefined method`each' for nil:NilClass`
.

```
<% @taskEdit.each do |task| %>
      <%= task.id %>
```

In that case what is the best way to prevent a nil from breaking my code?

Edit 
Controller code

```
  def index
    @canEditTasks = Accessor.where("accessor_id = ? AND access_right = ?", current_user, true)
  end

  def show
     @taskEdit = @canEditTasks
     rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
       render :file => 'public/404.html'
  end
```

View code

```
<div>
  <% @taskEdit.each do |task| %>
      <%= task.id %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: ActiveRecord’s `where` shouldn’t ever return `nil`. Also `canEditTask` is not the same as `@canEditTask`. Regardless, if `@taskEdit` is still `nil`, you have a completely different problem.

Comment: I updated my post according to changes in my code. I do still get a nil. At the moment my table is empty

Comment: Can we see the rest of that action's code? (specifically the part where `@taskEdit` is defined)

Comment: Your query looks a little malformed; accessor_id or user_id?

Comment: accessor_id is the right value. 
ctcherry - added the code. Please let me know if you'd like to see any other part of it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you assign `@taskEdit = @canEditTasks` in the `show` action, `@canEditTasks` is nil, which means `@taskEdit` is also nil.

Actions are run one at a time, it seems your code is expecting `index` to run first, and then `show` would run after that. That isn't how Rails works by default. If you want to run some code that is shared between several actions, I would suggest a `before_filter`.

```
before_filter :set_can_edit_tasks

def index; end

def show
  @taskEdit = @canEditTasks
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
    render :file => 'public/404.html'
end

private

def set_can_edit_tasks
  @canEditTasks = Accessor.where("accessor_id = ? AND access_right = ?", current_user, true)
end
```

Comment: I actually do not want to do that :) I just made a rookie mistake. I appreciate your help

Answer (score 3):

You are setting `@canEditTasks` in your index method and trying to use it in your show method... if you are confused by this you should probably go back to the basics and read/watch some Rails tutorials (sorry if I'm missing something here...).

Comment: facepalm, thanks. Although your answer could be less aggressive :)

Comment: How is that aggressive?

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer to use a .to_a after the active record where. so no error when a nil array is looped ;) avoids condition in views.